# How to enumerate certain pixels using glsl shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

For example, I have 16x9 picture which has 14 white pixels. Using imageAtomicAdd I can count total amount of white pixels.
But how I can enumerate these pixels in order of appearance (from 1 to 14).

[image: Example picture]

Comment: What do you want to do with the white pixels when you enumerate them?

Comment: One idea is to form a linked list e.g. by using imageAtomicExchange. Perhaps you say that pixel 0,0 is the head of the list and then when adding a pixel to the head of the list, you store the coordinates of the old head in the pixel you are adding.

Comment: @user253751: You could also write to a SSBO in any order (aka, in the order that is returned by an atomic counter) and do a second render path to sort it afterwards. But what's best depends on what op actually wants to do with the information afterwards.

Comment: this sounds like a task for compute shader